# Unity Changing Material Tiling per Gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've written a script that is supposed to make tiling materials easier. I was tired of constantly re-adjusting the tiling settings of materials on my walls as I resized them.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
 public class AutoTiler : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float xScaleMult = 1;
     public float yScaleMult = 1;
     private Material texture;
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if (!texture)
         {
             texture = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material; //get the material if it is null
         }
         
         //set the material scale based on the size of the object
         texture.mainTextureScale = new Vector2(Mathf.Max(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.z) * xScaleMult, transform.localScale.y * yScaleMult);
     }
 }
```

However, every time I reload the scene, I get an error message saying:

> Instantiating material due to calling renderer.material during edit mode. This will leak materials into the scene. You most likely want to use renderer.sharedMaterial instead.

I've looked up this error but I can't quite figure out how to solve it. I understand that I'm copying the material in order to change it, but that is the desired result, as it needs different tiling settings for every wall, so that it does not appear stretched. Currently the code works, but fills the console with this error message. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

in editor you can use **sharedmaterial** instead **material** property, something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class AutoTiler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float xScaleMult = 1;
    public float yScaleMult = 1;
    private Material material;

    private Material Material
    {
        get
        {
            if (material == null)
            {
                MeshRenderer render = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                material = render.sharedMaterial;
#else
                material = render.material;
#endif
            }
            return material;
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //set the material scale based on the size of the object
        Material.mainTextureScale = new Vector2(Mathf.Max(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.z) * xScaleMult, transform.localScale.y * yScaleMult);
    }
}
```

for more details about difference between material and sharedmaterial see :

http://gyanendushekhar.com/2018/09/23/difference-material-shared-material-unity-tutorial/

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterial.html